# How do I write key and array value from JS to JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How do I write key and array value from JS to JSON? And if the key value is the same, how do I overwrite it when there is an array value change in the existing key?

What I need as the result :

```
{
    "EX1.json_001": [[
       {"name": "name1"},
       {"name": "name2"},
       {"name": "name3"}
    ],[{"name": "name4"},
       {"name": "name5"},
       {"name": "name6"}
    ]],
    "EX1.json_002" : [[
    ...
    ]],
    ...
}
```

I can write the value now from JS to JSON like below..

```
[[
       {"name": "name1"},
       {"name": "name2"},
       {"name": "name3"}
    ],[{"name": "name4"},
       {"name": "name5"},
       {"name": "name6"}
    ]]
```

However, when I write it again, it overwrites, not adds. So What I thought is to add a key for each value (e.g."EX1.json_001"). I think I need to stringify key and value. If JSON file has the same key, value is changed and if JSON file doesn't have the matched key, key and value are added.

Do you know how to use key and value from JS to JSON?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to convert Object of array to array of array?

Comment: No, Array of Array will be the value in JSON. What I need is to add Key.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have in the beginning and what you want as end result?

Comment: Yes, I added it in the post.

Comment: Based on your question, what i understood is you need to add 2 key with same name, but it is not possible, because an object must contain unique attribute key.

Comment: "EX1.json_001" and "EX1.json_002" are keys, and they have different name.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. If you need to convert JS object to JSON, then you can use JSON.stringify(). If this is not the scnerio, please elaborate your question with your existing source code.

Comment: What I wanted to ask was how to write JS object to JSON without overwriting. Now, I have array of array in JS and I used JSON.stringify(), so it was written in JSON. But I need to write other array of array as well. That's why I thought unique key would be needed.

Comment: I guess he has some json and he wants to add to it but instead he overwrites his json with the changes that he wanted to do to original json.

Comment: I have one json file and need to add to it but it overwrites whenever I add new things from JS, so I thought unique keys would be needed. That's why I asked how to add new key to json if there's no same key. Also, if there's same key, I need to check and overwrite values in it.

Comment: You should not manipulate JSON itself, you need to parse it into javascript data structures, change them and then stringify result and assign that as updated JSON.